# Requsts Python Ошибка

Tags: python

Есть некоторые сложности. Я хочу импортировать `requests`. Когда я пытаюсь написать в cmd `python get-pip.py`, cmd говорит

> there's no such file or directory

Answer (score 2):

Для начала вы должны скачать Pythob с [офф. сайта](https://www.python.org/downloads/):

Затем установите `pip` из терминала

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

Потом установите `requests`

```
pip3 install requests
```

Comment: Вопрос был задан на английском языке, собственно и ответ такой же. Думаю что это парень случайно забродивший на русский Overflow.

Comment: Предложил перевод, и для вопроса, и для ответа